# GPU Timeout Error

Tags: error, gpu

I am getting an error when trying to render an image:

```
Command buffer not completed. status = 5.
(PSO_GENERIC.prefix_sum):Error Domain=MTLCommandBufferErrorDomain Code = 2
"Caused GPU Timeout Error (00000002:kIOAccelCommandBufferCallbackErrorTimeout)"
UserInfo={MSLocalizedDescription=Caused GPU Timeout Error(00000002:kIOAccelCommandBufferCallbackErrorTimeout)}
```

I started experiencing it on 3.6.0 - then I tried updating to 4.0.2 but continued to experience it. When I tested with much lower geometry files or even files I had previously successfully rendered, I continued to get the error.

MBP 2019

- 2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
- AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 8 GB
- Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB
- 64 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
- macOS 14.2.1

I'm new to troubleshooting, so please let me know if there are steps/tools I can use to find out more info on what the problem is or if there is more info I can provide to be helpful.